# Matching params object[] with function params

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm new to using C# and I'm trying to the same as the ellipsis operator does in C++ with variadic template to pass multiple params.

I saw that I can do this:

```
void MyFunction(params object[] myParams)
{
    // here I can do whatever I want
}

// calling my function
MyFunction(12, true, "My Params", 45.8);
```

But I need to pass params to make it match with another function, for example:

```
void MyFunction(params object[] myParams)
{
    // This is what I need to do
    AnotherFunction(myParams);
}

void AnotherFunction(int param1, bool param2, string param3, double param4)
{
    // Here I can do whatever I want
}

// calling my function
MyFunction(12, true, "My Params", 45.8);
```

Is this supported in C#?? If so, how can I do this?

Regards

Comment: Sure, but not with shorthand: `AnotherFunction((int) myParams[0], (bool) myParams[1], ...`). If you want to do this dynamically, it'll take some really icky reflection and be slow to boot. C# does not (really) have variadic argument lists; `params` is just syntactic sugar so you don't have to write out an array allocation. Make sure this serves an actual purpose that can't be done more cleanly in some other way (like passing a specific class to capture the parameters, or a `Dictionary`, or even an anonymous object that you reflect over) and you're not just trying to copy a C++ idiom.

Comment: Swap them over; `void AnotherFunction(int param1, bool param2, string param3, double param4) => MyFunction(param1, param2, param3, param4)` and make MyFunction do the work. Call `AnotherFunction(12, true, "My Params", 45.8);` instead